# How to position fancyhdr[R]?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, header-footer, fancyhdr

I cant get the right header/footer on the right position. It should be positioned 3cm from right page end. How can i achieve that?

Sample Document:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}

% includes (they are maybe currently not needed, but later)
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ngerman}
\usepackage{pageslts}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage[colorlinks=false]{hyperref}
\usepackage{floatflt}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\pagestyle{fancy}

% Layout anpassen
\setlength{\hoffset}{0.46cm}
\setlength{\voffset}{-0.04cm}
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{0pt}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0pt}
\setlength{\marginparsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\textwidth}{15cm}
\setlength{\topmargin}{0pt}
\setlength{\headsep}{17pt}
\setlength{\textheight}{227mm}
\setlength{\footskip}{29pt}

% Kopf/Fußzeile
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[R]{Rechts}
\fancyhead[L]{Links}
\fancyfoot[R]{Rechts}
\fancyfoot[L]{Links}
\renewcommand\headrule{\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}}
\renewcommand\footrule{\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}\\}

\pagenumbering{arabic}

\begin{document} 
\section{Ein Titel}
\Blindtext
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do yo mean 3 cm from the physical page end, or from the end of line?

Comment: Rather than playing with `\hoffset` and so on, it's better to use the `geometry` package, that makes it easier to specify the page parameters. For instance, in order to have equal 3cm margins at both sides, just `textwidth=15cm` is sufficient.

Comment: Note also that `fancyhdr` is not recommended for usage with `scrartcl` and `scrpage2` is probably better, in this case.

Comment: BTW, [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: @egreg: i've tried using the geometry package, but it looked more wrong like my case (in combination with fancyhdr). But with the answer of karlkoeller it works fine. Do you have more documentation, or better: is there a central place for docs, where i can look first before asking? (please don't say google :), i've tried that)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the rule is `\textwidth` long and the right headers and footers don't fit, since you've declared `\textwidth` to be `15cm`.

Anyway, all these declarations

```
% Layout anpassen
\setlength{\hoffset}{0.46cm}
\setlength{\voffset}{-0.04cm}
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{0pt}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0pt}
\setlength{\marginparsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\textwidth}{15cm}
\setlength{\topmargin}{0pt}
\setlength{\headsep}{17pt}
\setlength{\textheight}{227mm}
\setlength{\footskip}{29pt}
```

should not be made directly, but with the help of the [`geometry`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/geometry) package or with the facilities provided by KOMA classes (see Chapter 2 of KOMA-script [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguien.pdf)), but I'll leave that to you.

The most important thing is that KOMA classes provide an own method to deal with headers and footers (see Chapter 5 of the documentation) through the `scrpage2` package.

In the following MWE I've substituted all `fancyhdr` commands with the corresponding `scrpage2` ones (old ones are commented):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}

% includes (they are maybe currently not needed, but later)
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ngerman}
\usepackage{pageslts}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage[colorlinks=false]{hyperref}
\usepackage{floatflt}
\usepackage{scrpage2}   % \usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\pagestyle{scrheadings} % \pagestyle{fancy}

% Layout anpassen
\setlength{\hoffset}{0.46cm}
\setlength{\voffset}{-0.04cm}
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{0pt}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0pt}
\setlength{\marginparsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\textwidth}{15cm}
\setlength{\topmargin}{0pt}
\setlength{\headsep}{17pt}
\setlength{\textheight}{227mm}
\setlength{\footskip}{29pt}

% Kopf/Fußzeile
\clearscrheadfoot    % \fancyhf{}
\ohead{Rechts}       % \fancyhead[R]{Rechts}
\ihead{Links}        % \fancyhead[L]{Links}
\ofoot{Rechts}       % \fancyfoot[R]{Rechts}
\ifoot{Links}        % \fancyfoot[L]{Links}
\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{\normalfont}
\setheadsepline{1pt} % \renewcommand\headrule{\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}}
\setfootsepline{1pt} % \renewcommand\footrule{\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}\\}

\pagenumbering{arabic}

\begin{document}
\section{Ein Titel}
\Blindtext
\end{document}
```

and this is the result:

[image]